# Publish JSON with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geojson, json

I generated a `JSON` by a `PHP` script and now want to load this `JSON` to GeoServer. So far I just found ways to publish `SHP` files but not `JSON`...

Comment: Do you want to load JSON into GeoServer (i.e. use it as a data source),  or publish (Geo)JSON, they are different things.

Comment: I want to load JSON into GeoServer with the overall goal to provide it via WFS

Comment: You don't need to have to load JSON into GeoServer to serve it out as JSON though.  GeoServer can convert from multiple formats to multiple formats.  So if you have a shapefile as datasource you can through WFS serve it out as JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoTools (which provides the underlying data management for GeoServer) has an unsupported `GeoJsonDatastore` (`gt-geojsonstore`) which would allow you to publish GeoJson files via GeoServer if you drop the jar file into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

But it would be very slow and would lack the nice GUI of a finished data plugin. GeoJSON is better suited as a transfer format rather than a storage format so you would be better off using QGis or `ogr2ogr` to convert it into a better format such as GeoPackage or load it into a database.

Comment: my overall goal is to provide the data via a WFS (no visualization). Do you recommend to convert the format for this case as well?
I was already thinking about `ogr2ogr`/QGis/GDAL but I was not sure how to realise it because it should be able to run on a server more or less on its own

Comment: I added the jar to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder, but there is no new data store in the GeoServer data store menu...      
I used the jar from this address: [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-geojsondatastore/24.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-geojsondatastore/24.2)

  -   Did I miss something out?

Comment: GeoJSON does not support any indexes. But if the amount of data is small or your WFS users do not use spatial filters (including BBOX) or attribute filters then GeoJSON may be usable.